# AWS Cognito: changing the aws_user_pools_web_client_id

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I need to change the value of aws_user_pools_web_client_id so that it points to a different web client id. Obviously, I cannot simply edit the aws-exports file, so how do I correctly change this value?

```
/* eslint-disable */
// WARNING: DO NOT EDIT. This file is automatically generated by AWS Amplify. It will be overwritten.

const awsmobile = {
    "aws_project_region": "us-east-2",
    "aws_cognito_identity_pool_id": "us-east-2:8e691ef4-cca0-457e-9934-3a1846b0f28c",
    "aws_cognito_region": "us-east-2",
    "aws_user_pools_id": "us-east-2_cdT9gJH6x",
    "aws_user_pools_web_client_id": "3i3pj4u2aq4b9bq12i64ikvv6k",
    "oauth": {
        "domain": "nerdhub-dev.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com",
        "scope": [
            "phone",
            "email",
            "openid",
            "profile",
            "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin"
        ],
        "redirectSignIn": "http://localhost:3000/",
        "redirectSignOut": "http://localhost:3000/",
        "responseType": "code"
    },
    "federationTarget": "COGNITO_USER_POOLS"
};


export default awsmobile;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to be able to configure this in advance and change it with environments?

If so then you can use the following syntax and use variables - react for example would use the process.env.REACT_APP_...... syntax

```
Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    region: "",
    userPoolId: "",
    userPoolWebClientId: ""
  }
});
```

which are listed in full at [congito](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/start/q/platform/js#configure-your-application)